# OpenCV cv2.moments returns all moments to zero

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, geometry

For some reason that I cannot understand, the open cv function `cv2.moments` returns a dictionary with all zero values for the contour I am providing.
Here is a MWE:

```
contour = [[[271, 67]],
           [[274, 67]],
           [[275, 68]],
           [[278, 68]],
           [[279, 69]],
           [[283, 69]],
           [[284, 70]],
           [[287, 70]],
           [[288, 71]],
           [[291, 71]],
           [[292, 72]],
           [[295, 72]],
           [[292, 72]],
           [[291, 71]],
           [[288, 71]],
           [[287, 70]],
           [[284, 70]],
           [[283, 69]],
           [[279, 69]],
           [[278, 68]],
           [[275, 68]],
           [[274, 67]]]

contour = np.asarray(contour)
moments = cv2.moments(contour)
```

with the result:

```
print(moments)

{'m00': 0.0, 'm10': 0.0, 'm01': 0.0, 'm20': 0.0, 'm11': 0.0, 'm02': 0.0, 'm30': 0.0, 'm21': 0.0, 'm12': 0.0, 'm03': 0.0, 'mu20': 0.0, 'mu11': 0.0, 'mu02': 0.0, 'mu30': 0.0, 'mu21': 0.0, 'mu12': 0.0, 'mu03': 0.0, 'nu20': 0.0, 'nu11': 0.0, 'nu02': 0.0, 'nu30': 0.0, 'nu21': 0.0, 'nu12': 0.0, 'nu03': 0.0}
```

What is the meaning of this behaviour?
I believe this is because the contour is open, but i am not sure.
Is there a standard way to get rid of this behaviour by checking if the contour is open or closed beforehand?

Answer (score 5):

[image: contour points]

Those are the points of your contour. The GIF doesn't loop back-and-forth, it only plays forward. When the point "climbs back up again", those are not the same points, they are new points that just coincide with previous points. Inspect the points in your contour, you'll see it.

Your contour is ***not*** "open". That is not the issue. In OpenCV, all contours are considered closed. They needn't be dense either (1-pixel distance between points).

The issue is that `cv.moments()` has a bug and OpenCV contours are weird.

And your contour has no area *in the strict mathematical "polygon" sense* because it was calculated from a 1-pixel line.

***That*** is the bug in `cv.moments()`. It calculates those moments as if the contour were an actual *polygon*. It *should have* returned a non-zero area (`m00`) for this *contour* because the contour describes a non-zero-area connected component.

In OpenCV, contours describe the polygon **that would have to be drawn** with 1-pixel stroke to reproduce the border pixels of that connected component. The contour runs *ON* the border pixels, through their centers.

That means, if you have a 2 by 2 pixel rectangle, you get contour points *on* those border pixels, say (1,1), (2,1), (2,2), (1,2). The area of that is just 1 (taken as a mathematical polygon), when it should have been 4 (in OpenCV's notion of a contour). For a plain line, same thing, but now you've got zero area.

And your polygon indeed has zero area. You just don't see it because the line wasn't straight.

OpenCV could have defined contours to be zero-width lines that *circumscribe* the outer pixels of a connected component, i.e. run exactly along pixel edges. That would have required:

1. the drawing calls in OpenCV to not be as broken and neglected as they are (I'm being blunt but it's true)
2. the conventions for a contour to allow non-integer coordinates

Feel free to submit an [issue on OpenCV's github page](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues). The `cv.moments()` implementation needs a fix. The fix should probably be an additional flag to the call that distinguishes "contours" from proper polygons. That way, the mathematically correct behavior isn't lost, but instead made optional. Everyone calls that function on contours, so that should be the default.

---

The one other answer "works" because now `cv.moments()` is called on the ***mask** drawn from the contour* instead of the contour itself. You can just skip the entire contour calculation. Maybe work with `connectedComponents()` instead.

The other other answer's explanation is wrong but it doesn't suggest a fix, only to skip the situation.

Comment: Nice answer. If you find the other answers are wrong, you should downvote them. Down voting wrong answers is how the system intends those wrong answers from being seen as correct.

Comment: I spared the answer that contains an actual solution, even if it's "just" a workaround :)

Comment: …and for some reason the wrong answer got another upvote too. Sigh…