# contour array sometimes give 0 length

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

I am using contours to find a the coordinates of a ball on a table using opencv. The problem I am getting is sometimes I get the len of contour array as 0 which breaks my code ahead.
before this code I have a img file which is cropped and transformed using four_point_transform. The image is black background which while ball foreground.

```
threshold = cv2.threshold(img, 254, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]

contours,_ = cv2.findContours(threshold,cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
print('length of contours array:',len(contours))
```

I have tried changing the 254 values to 250 but it doesn't help me much.

Comment: That is likely because sometimes the function is not finding any contours in your image. That's just how the algorithm works. There are going to be cases where it fails to find what you want it to find. You need to modify the rest of the code so that it doesn't break when this happens. Alternately, you need to tune the parameters of the contour function itself so as to make it work it most of your data.

Comment: Same problem as this one: https://stackoverflow.com/q/62392240/7328782